# Twitter status count mismatch

Tags: twitter

I'm loading twitter statuses as follows and instead of 6 i'm getting 5 of them
if i change that to 5 i'm getting 4 so one less (count=1 gives 0 statuses)
https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/user_timeline.xml?count=6

i was reading documentation and they've mentioned retweets, which i think i don't
need however adding such param still give me one less
https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/user_timeline.xml?count=6&include_rts=true

as of now i'm simply loading more then i need and just presenting 6 but has anyone an
idea how this may be solved properly?

Answer (score 0):

Advice: If you want people to offer better help, provide some more information. For example, what language are you using? What environment? The code that is giving this issues would be helpful too. This will also help you to provide more and more specific tags so people with relevant expertise will notice the question and help you out.

My thoughts with this information is that its a problem with array indexes.
I don't know what experience you have with coding so if you know all this, please don't take offence, but when you use an array, the index starts at 0. So if you have an array with 6 items in, the indexes go from 0-5 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). So if you're trying to access elements 1-6 and you're starting from index 1, you will only be able to get items from index 1-5. Does that make sense?

If not, please provide more information and I'll take another look

Matt

Comment: Neither language, nor environment seems to play any role here. If you simply open this example link https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/oprah.xml?count=6 of Oprah tweets in your browser, you'll see only 4 statuses in the XML, changing count to 7 will give you 5